# Get list of users who have access to a hardware device

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using

```
SoftLayer_Account::getHardware
```

to get list of hardware in my account. How can I get list of users who have access to this hardware?

I dont want to go round about to get list of hardware a user has access to using

```
SoftLayer_User_Customer::getHardware
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can help you [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::getUsers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getUsers):

```
URL:
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[hardware_id]/getUsers

Method: GET
```

Comment: Yeah I figured this out. But in SoftLayer_Account::getVirtualGuests we have `users` datatype which  gives me a list of users who have access to that device. So that saves me a lot of softlayer API hits since access information is part of the same API. But in hardware object I dont have any such attribute so I have to hit softlayer API for each hardware device and then get the user access list. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Hi, I was executing some tests. Using this example: `https:/api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,hardware(SoftLayer_Hardware_Server)[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,users]]&resultLimit=0,1`. It seems that it is getting more users than accessed users. Maybe it helps you in something. I'll let know you if I have any news. (Note: I'm using result limits because mi account displays a lot data)